# jsp display random amount of rows from database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

I'm making a web-application with JSP and Servlets and I came accross this problem:
I have a table `users` and a `myeducations` table. These table relationship is established on user_id.

This is the table:

**myeducation**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ed_id | user_id | school_name | year_attended_from | year_attended_to | degree |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I want to display on a website (jsp) all of the user educations, but the number of educations user has is random: 1 user could have finished just 1 school, other could 3 and so on...

I understand how to retrieve just 1 row, the SQL is:

```
SELECT school_name 
FROM myeducation
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = myeducation.user_id;
```

But how to make this statement run in a loop, so that I get all the educations of a user, say if he has more than just 1. Then put them all in a session variable and display in a jsp's div.

Comment: Are checking for only one user? who had studied in multiple schools?

Comment: Yes, 1 particular user, who has random number of schools he studied in, i.e. rows in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve this using `joins` or `nested Query`

As per your current DB Design, you can achieve this by a simple query itself, Since Education table holds the USER_ID

```
SELECT school_name FROM myeducation myedu where user_id="SOME_ID_HERE"
```

For looping String Array in servlet, simply do like this

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
  arr.add(rs.getString("school_name "));
}
```

Comment: Ok, so then I store the results in List<String> or something? Then I set the session variables in my servlet like this? : for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) { session.setAttribute("sessionEducation" + i, myList.get[i]);}  How do I make my JSP then to display this?

Comment: Check now @qazerty23. Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me to get on the right track, i'll figure the rest :)

Comment: Thanks @Sireesh. I am going to use For Each loop in my JSP, to get all the values from array. Just wondering, is it okay to use For Each in jsp?

Comment: Thats fine. As long as it is not enterprise