# Display multiple rows in jsp page from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to display multiple rows of a mysql table on a jsp page. I can successfully read one row from the database and display it on my jsp page. For some reason, my code only displays one row. Could you please help me figure out how to display multiple rows on the jsp page?

**tableView.jsp FILE**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<style>
    table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    }
</style>
<style>
    body {margin:0;}

    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    .topnav a {
     float: left;
     display: block;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
     color: black;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     color: white;
    }
    .topnave {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #737373;
    }

    .topnave a {
     float: center;
     display: block;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
     display: inline-block;
    }

    .topnave a:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
     color: black;
    }

    .topnave a.active {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<jsp:include page="_header.jsp" />
<body>

<div class="topnav">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tableView">Table View</a>
</div>
</body>
<head>
    <title>Table View</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h3 style="font-family:verdana; font-size:30px; color:green">Table View</h3>

This is actual data from the Groguru database from the "sw_releases_table". <br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Unique ID</th>
    <th>Release Name</th>
    <th>Update Date</th>
    <th>Release Date</th>
    <th>Release Notes</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>State</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>${unique_id}</td>
    <td>${release_name}</td>
    <td>${update_date}</td>
    <td>${release_date}</td>
    <td>${release_notes}</td>
    <td>${filename}</td>
    <td>${state}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<div class="topnave">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/views/addRowView.jsp">Add Row</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteRow">Delete Row</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editRow">Edit Row</a>
</div>>

</center>>
<jsp:include page="_footer.jsp" />


</body>

</html>
```

**tableView.java FILE**

```
package com.grogurutest.simplewebapp.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class tableView
 */
@WebServlet("/tableView")
public class tableView extends HttpServlet {
      public Connection connect = null;
      public Statement statement = null;
      public PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
      public ResultSet resultSet = null;;

      final public String host = "localhost:3306";
      final public String user = "user";
      final public String passwd = "Lasilka00";

      public String valuePicker(String columnName) throws Exception, ServletException, IOException {
             // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


              // Setup the connection with the DB


              // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
              connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imported?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=" + user + "&password=" + passwd );
              statement = connect.createStatement();              
              // Result set get the result of the SQL query
              resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sw_releases_table");
              //writeResultSet(resultSet);

              String columnVal = "initial";
              while (resultSet.next()) {
          if (Objects.equals(columnName, "unique_id")){
                columnVal =  Integer.toString(resultSet.getInt("unique_id"));
                  System.out.println("columnVal = " + columnVal);
                  System.out.println("a checkpoint");
                  close();
                return columnVal;

            } if (Objects.equals(columnName, "release_name")){
                columnVal = resultSet.getString("release_name");
                  System.out.println("b checkpoint");
                  close();
                return columnVal;
          } if (Objects.equals(columnName, "update_date")){

                columnVal =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(resultSet.getDate("update_date"));
                  System.out.println("c checkpoint");
                  close();
                return columnVal;

          } if (Objects.equals(columnName, "release_date")){

                columnVal =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(resultSet.getDate("release_date"));
                  System.out.println("d checkpoint");
                  close();
                return columnVal;

          } if (Objects.equals(columnName, "release_notes")){

                columnVal =  resultSet.getString("release_notes");
                  System.out.println("e checkpoint");
                  close();
                return columnVal;

          } if (Objects.equals(columnName, "filename")){

                columnVal =  resultSet.getString("filename");
                  System.out.println("f checkpoint");
                  close();
                return columnVal;

          } if (Objects.equals(columnName, "state")){

                columnVal =  resultSet.getString("state");
                  System.out.println("g checkpoint");
                return columnVal;

          } else {
              System.out.println("h checkpoint");
              close();
              return "Not working";
          }   
        } 
              return columnVal;
}

      public void close() {
            try {
              if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
              }

              if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
              }

              if (connect != null) {
                connect.close();
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("exception with closing");
            }
          }



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public tableView() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
                    try {
                        String unique_id = valuePicker("unique_id");
                        System.out.println(unique_id);
                        request.setAttribute("unique_id", unique_id);   

                        String release_name = valuePicker("release_name");
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("release_name", release_name);
                        System.out.println(release_name);

                        String update_date = valuePicker("update_date");
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("update_date", update_date);          
                        System.out.println(update_date);

                        String release_date = valuePicker("release_date");
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("release_date", release_date);
                        System.out.println(release_date);

                        String release_notes = valuePicker("release_notes");
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("release_notes", release_notes);
                        System.out.println(release_notes);

                        String filename = valuePicker("filename");
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("filename", filename);
                        System.out.println(filename);

                        String state = valuePicker("state");
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("state", state);
                        System.out.println(state);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("exception 7");
                    } finally {
                        close();
                    }
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/views/tableView.jsp");
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139707/jsp-display-random-amount-of-rows-from-database?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a POJO of all your attributes with all the getters and setters method.

   public class Release {
       private String uniqueId;
       private String releaseName;
       //.... follow the pattern

   ```
   //getters, setters
   public String getUniqueId() {
       return uniqueId;
   }
   public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
       this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
   }
   public String getReleaseName() {
       return releaseName;
   }
   public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
       this.releaseName = releaseName;
   }
   ```

   }
2. In java code, create a list of your POJO.

   `List<Release> releaseList = new ArrayList<Release>();
    releaseList = getListofReleaseFromDB();`
3. Set the whole list as attribute in request.

   `request.setAttribute("releaseList", releaseList);`
4. Retrieve this list in JSP and use JSTL to dynamically generate a table with all the rows. You should be able to find ample examples of this in Stackoverflow.

Comment: what is a POJO?

Comment: @user3858820 POJO stands for "Plain Old Java Object"

Comment: How do I create a POJO?

Comment: Its a regular java bean class with a bunch of fields which have getters and setters.  Just see what object makes sense in terms of your requirements.

Comment: I am new to this. What do I put in the getter and setter methods? also, where do I actually retrieve the info from the database? Please go into a lot of detail, I don't really understand this.